# Sending the User's Country and IP Hidden Input

Tags: javascript, html

I Have an HTML Form And I Want to Find Out the IP and Country When Users Submit the Form.

I Can See the User's Information, But How Can I Send It Hidden?

What Do I Need To Add To My Form Or Javascript Code?

```
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>

        <script>$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
            $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
            $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
            $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        }, "jsonp");</script>
```

Example: For example, This is How I Can Get UTM Information. In the Same Way, I Want to be Able to Get the IP and Country Like This. I Use Webhook in My Post.

```
<input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="">

    <script>var queryForm=function(e){var t=!(!e||!e.reset)&&e.reset,n=window.location.toString().split("?");if(n.length>1){var o=n[1].split("&");for(s in o){var r=o[s].split("=");(t||null===sessionStorage.getItem(r[0]))&&sessionStorage.setItem(r[0],decodeURIComponent(r[1]))}}for(var i=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden], input[type=text]"),s=0;s<i.length;s++){var a=sessionStorage.getItem(i[s].name);a&&(document.getElementsByName(i[s].name)[0].value=a)}};setTimeout(function(){queryForm()},3e3);</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying you want to send it hidden? the input to the fetch api? (you can't); the information you've got after fetching the api? does it make any sense? I don't understand, please make it more clear.

Comment: I Want to Send the User's IP and Country as Hidden Input.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but can't you just add 2 `<input type="hidden"` fields and populate their val with the values returned from ipinfo.io. E.g. `$('#hidden_input_country').val(response.country)`

Comment: those two values are information you grabbed from ipinfo.io doing that ajax request in your js code. There's no hint on how are you crafting any other submit form of those info to any web url. That's what you meant to do? send those informations that were just grabbed when the user loaded that page, to another url?

Comment: I Would Like to Make a Submission Similar to the UTM Hidden Submission. I have Attached the Example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have successfully received the data (ip, lcoation). In your JS you write the values into your HTML (id="ip", id="address"). Now you can collect the data again when sending it to your server.

```
const ip = document.getElementById('ip');
const address = document.getElementById('address');

const data = { ip: ip, address: address };

fetch('https://youDomain.tld/profile', {
  method: 'POST', 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

And if you do it hidden means that you have to add some style to hide the div tags with the ip=ip and id=address. Inline style `<div id="ip" style="display:none;"></div>`